# how to include content from an external site?

Tags: javascript, iframe, external

This is a great big mess...

I know I could use an iframe, but the problem there is that there are some cross-site limitations that wind up botching what I'm trying to do.  Namely, the source content is a fixed height div that allows scrolling, but without the scrollbar.  If I load that up in an iframe, it won't have the same effect.  It either insists on having a scrollbar, or it doesn't scroll at all.  I've been trying to find a way around this, but the **destination server doesn't have php available**, so I'm flat-out stuck on how to do this...

On the source server, I tried writing all of the content to a php variable like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var mycontent = '<?php print $content; ?>';
</script>
```

and then calling that variable in my test.js file and when I use an alert, I get the text (also on the source server), like this:

```
var content = mycontent;
alert(content);
```

It works, but, not from the destination server.  So, on the destination server, if I use:

```
 <script src="http://mysite.com/test.js"></script>
```

And try to use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write('content');</script>
```

It doesn't print anything out... I'm assuming because of cross-site limitations?  I'm desperate for a workaround...  Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a **server-side** XHR request, grab the content, and include it when your page is served-up.

Answer (score 0):

It should be perfectly well possible to do a

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mysite.com/test.js"></script>
```

and in the Javascript, *without* `<script type....`, do

```
document.write('blah');
document.write('blah');
document.write('blah');
document.write('blah');
document.write('blah');
```

this will work fine across domains. I think your problem is that you embed `<script>` tags into the js file, which is wrong. Such things will pop up as syntax errors in Firefox's Error Console, an invaluable tool when developing  JavaScript.

There's a downside to this approach by the way: If your target server serving the JS is down, the rendering of the document that embeds the script will be delayed.

Comment: except that you probably want the `content` variable, not the `'content'` literal string.

Comment: The js doesn't have <script type>.  It's just:

$(document).ready(function() {
        var content = mycontent;
 document.write(content);
});


All I get is: [object Window]

Comment: Jquery code? In a remote script? Together with document.write? I doubt that is going to work. You should have mentioned that earlier. Can you post your full code?